# React js Apollo Destructuring Result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client

This is my second simple query from the Apollo client.  My first attempt queries a list of users and displays them, works just fine.  I don't understand what the differences between my two query functions.

So I'm trying to make a super simple query from an Apollo client.  The query is two fields the id and client name.  The query is executed and results are returned, verified by console.log(data).  So I believe the server is work properly and the query is working.   I ran the Apollo codegen to download and create the ts files that contain my interfaces.

I also have copied the output from Apollo's Playground and created little plain java script destructure.  I was able to destructure the result quiet easily, but I can't apply that code to the React project.  Best I can seem to do is display "pt_Clients" nothing else.   I have been stuck on this for embarrassing amount time.

clients.tsx

```
export const GET_CLIENTS = gql`
  query pt_Clients {
    pt_Clients { 
      id 
      clientname 
    }
  }`;
 
interface ClientsProps extends RouteComponentProps { }

const PTClients: React.FC<ClientsProps> = () => {
  const {
    data,
    loading,
    error
  } = useQuery< 
                pt_ClientsTypes.pt_Clients_pt_Client
              >(GET_CLIENTS);

  if (loading) return <Loading />;
  if (error) return <p>ERROR</p>;
  if (!data) return <p>Not found</p>;

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <h3>Client List</h3>
          {console.log(data)}
          {
            data && 
            Object.keys(data).map((client: any) => ( 
              <li> 
                <Link to={'/admin/pt/clients/:' + client.id} >{client.clientname}</Link>
                
              </li>  
            )) 
          }
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <Switch> 
        <Route  
          path='/admin/pt/clients/:id'
          render={({match}) => {
            const { id } = match.params;    
            return <AdminClient clientid={id} />
          }}
        /> 
      </Switch>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default PTClients;
```

my codegen file types/pt_Clients.ts

```
/* tslint:disable */
/* eslint-disable */
// @generated
// This file was automatically generated and should not be edited.

// ====================================================
// GraphQL query operation: pt_Clients
// ====================================================

export interface pt_Clients_pt_Client {
  __typename: "pt_Client";
  id: number,
  clientid: number; 
  status: number | null;
  clientname: string | null; 
}

export interface pt_Clients {
  pt_Client: pt_Clients_pt_Client | null;
}
```

Playground Results

```
{
  "data": {
    "pt_Clients": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "clientname": "Client A",
        "__typename": "pt_Client"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "clientname": "Client B",
        "__typename": "pt_Client"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "clientname": "Client C",
        "__typename": "pt_Client"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "clientname": "Client D",
        "__typename": "pt_Client"
      } 
    ]
  },
  "loading": false,
  "networkStatus": 7,
  "stale": false
}
```

Thanks for taking the time to read and any help that offered.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So **first things first**.

The *clients* array is in `data.pt_Clients` not in data itself. So to render the list of clients, you need to do `data.pt_Clients.map((client : any))`

**Second**, the `to` prop for `Link` should not contain the `:` character. It should be there, as you've correctly written in`Route` component's `path` prop only.

Check the following code

```
<ul>
    <h3>Client List</h3>
    {console.log(data)}
    {
        data && 
        data.pt_Clients.map((client: any) => ( 
            <li> 
                <Link to={`/admin/pt/clients/${client.id}`}>
                    {client.clientname}
                </Link>
            </li>  
         )) 
    }
</ul>
```

On a sidenote, the `li`, and `Link` elements **should** contain a`key` prop.

Comment: That's because it doesn't. Typescript is not allowing you to access the field because you've cast the useQuery to type `pt_Clients_pt_Client`. Try casting the useQuery to `any`type and see.

Comment: I have tried to do the `data.pt_clients.map` Property 'pt_Clients' does not exist on type 'pt_Clients_pt_Client'.  TS2339.  After looking at my user interface code, I changed pt_client from `pt_Client: pt_Clients_pt_Client | null;` to `pt_Clients: (pt_Clients_pt_Client | null)[];` to match what the user interface has.   But I still can't use data.pt_Clients.   Thanks for the suggestion and the pointers.   Im still very new in this area

Comment: You should also be able to do it by casting useQuery to type `pt_Clients` like `useQuery<pt_ClientsTypes.pt_Clients>` and then in the map function, cast the client to type `pt_Clients_pt_Client` like `data.pt_Clients.map((client: pt_ClientsTypes.pt_Clients_pt_Client) => (...)) `